# laravel4 Response::json(array()); not work in hosting

Tags: php, json, laravel, response

**HOSTING**
I tried to response json in hosting with follow the example http://laravel.com/docs/responses#special-responses

```
return Response::json(array('name' => 'Steve', 'state' => 'CA'));
```

but response headers is

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/RDON9.jpg]

and response: Reload the page to get source for: httx://xxxx.com 
So, I'm try **`echo Response::json(array(...));`** result is

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/OBNgn.jpg]

I must to use it work:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

---

**MY LOCAL**

and my localhost `Response::json(array());` is work! version of the same
What should I do?
help me please.

Comment: Can you see what is installed on your hosting vs local using <?php phpinfo();? on both? It's possible the json extension is missing from your server. It is supposed to come bundled with PHP 5.2 and up but you know what they say about assuming

Comment: hosting is use PHP Version 5.4.15 same me in local. I think it work for laravel

Comment: try this: return Response::json($data, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));

Comment: I had tried it. But was ineffective.

Comment: It *may* be related to Varnish, but I can't say what to do to determine if it is and how to solve the issue.

Comment: With the few information you've provided, I can say somewhere before `return Response::json ...` your PHP script is sendign a header to the browser.

Comment: can you post the controller function? Also the JS function please. I had a similar problem with a cheap hosting: changing hosting provider fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

When you use Response::json($yourarray); you are going to be sending a header with the json data.

If you are not using jquery or javascript to accept the response, and are instead trying to pass data to another method, try:

return json_encode($yourarray)

Answer (score 0):

This may solve the problem:

```
return Response::json(array('name' => 'Steve', 'state' => 'CA'))
               ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```